# Apply a function to all rows using 2 columns and creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a Dataframe with two columns (date as index)

```
date       col_a   col_b
1.1.2020    23     34
```

and I want to apply a function using the 2 columns and creating a third one (error)

```
date      col_a  col_b   col_error
1.1.2020   23     34     0.4
```

here is my Dataframe [image: Dataframe]
and below the code with the TypeError (sorry I can't provide the data :( )

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

# Apply a lambda function to each row by calculating the error
result['mape'] = result.apply(mean_absolute_percentage_error(test_df, pred_df))
result

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-681609c31734> in <module>
      4 
      5 # Apply a lambda function to each row by calculating the error
----> 6 result['mape'] = result.apply(mean_absolute_percentage_error(test_df, pred_df))
      7 result

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6911             kwds=kwds,
   6912         )
-> 6913         return op.get_result()
   6914 
   6915     def applymap(self, func):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    290 
    291         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 292         self.apply_series_generator()
    293 
    294         # wrap results

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    319             try:
    320                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 321                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    322                     keys.append(v.name)
    323             except Exception as e:

TypeError: ("'numpy.float64' object is not callable", 'occurred at index Night_Cons(+)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to manipulate the columns and add a new one would be something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a': [23], 'col_b': [34]}, 
    index=[pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')])
print(df)

            col_a  col_b
2020-01-01     23     34

df['col_error'] = abs((df['col_a'] - df['col_b'])/df['col_b'])
print(df)

            col_a  col_b  col_error
2020-01-01     23     34   0.323529
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple approach

Answer (score 1):

To create a new column from the existing one you can simply use a lambda function. For instance, if you your new column to be the difference from the previous ones:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.col_1 - row.col_2, axis=1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: very useful ... Thks